# mvvm prism 6 forward stack is cleared when navigating to new view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism, journal

I'm rather new to prism.  I have a main content region that shows one view at a time.  If i display a listview, then execute the editcommand to navigate to the detailview of the current item, my navigation works as expected.  I can go back to the listview and then forward to the detail view.  If I go back to the listview and edit another item, its view is displayed as expected, but the previous detail view is now removed from the forward stack.  Actually viewing the prism code, the forward stack is cleared when the RecordNavigation method is executed.  Is this by design?  I would like to have the new detail view be the current item, but retain all of the views within the forward stack?  I'm assuming i will have to override the RegionNavigationJournal, but was curious if there is something I'm missing.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is by design and works exactly as a back/forward navigation system should.  Look at your favorite internet browser.  Given I navigate like this:

PersonLsitView -> PersonAView

Then pressed back, I would be at PersonListView again with the PersonAView in my forward stack.

Now from PersonListView I navigate to PersonBView.  Now press the back button and now I am back at PersonListView, except this time going forward would be PersonBView.

It would make no sense to have PersonAView be the view that appears when you navigate forward from PersonListView after coming back from PersonBView.

Honestly, the behavior you want will not make any sense to your users.

Comment: Hi Brian:  Thanks for taking the time to answer.  Actually i would still expect PersonBView to be displayed when clicking forward from the PersonListView, but that the Forward button would still allow you to get to PersonAView once the PersonBView had been re-activated.  This is my first WPF app, and I'm trying to get away from my usual tabbed visual studio type winform ui, and playing around with a single main content region. Is it wrong to want a journal mechanism to insert a new view after its parent(NavigateFrom) view, but retain all previously opened views in the forward stack?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely unorthodox.  That navigation pattern would be very confusing, and not what a user would be expecting.